# Firestore data loading memory overhead

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

My React Native app loads some documents from Firestore and stores them locally in AsyncStorage. Depending on the user's app usage, this document collection can become quite large. It might happen that the documents of a specific user grow into the dozens of megabytes, together (e.g. 500 documents of about 100kB each).

(It might be an antipattern to use Firestore for documents which are that big. However, most use cases are dealing with a small number of small documents. Still, we need to make the app ready for power users)

The app uses AsyncStorage as a local cache of the documents' data. If the data is already there, nothing gets loaded from Firestore (at least initially). If not, then the data is loaded from Firestore and stored in AsyncStorage (we cannot use Firestore's cache because we transform the data when loading it, and we need a deterministic cache).

What we noticed is, when loading the data from Firestore, we end up with a huge memory consumption, even after there was enough time for Garbage Collection to collect everything. When loading the data from AsyncStorage, the memory consumption is much lower, even though we have the same data in memory.

To make sure that this memory is still retained (i.e. that my observation does not depend on Garbage Collection timing), I loaded about a Gigabyte of Firestore data onto a device. There were several memory warnings, and judging by the memory consumption observed, GC was working hard to collect as much as possible, but the memory consumption was still several Gigabytes higher than compared to when the data was loaded from AsyncStorage.

It seems that the Firestore client either has

- a huge memory overhead when loading documents from Firestore, and this memory overhead leaks and is not collected by GC
- or some caching mechanism that leaves the query results in memory

**Have I overlooked something? Is there some in-memory cache enabled by default? Does Firestore keep a copy of the data in memory to detect changes to the documents?**

Comment: I suggest editing the question to be more clear about how your are making observations and taking measurements with respect to specific code written that deals with Firestore.  We should be able to reproduce the behavior you describe using your instructions.

Comment: @DougStevenson thank you Doug. If you tell me this should not be, I'm going to try to isolate it and file a bug.

Comment: Since I can't see your code, I don't know what sort of behavior to expect.  There's nothing here that strongly suggests a problem with Firestore, or something else, or maybe even just mismatched expectations about how the APIs work.  If you are absolutely able to narrow this down to a problem with Firestore with a clear and straightforward reproduction, then you have a bug report (but only if your expectations of the APIs match its intent).

Comment: @DougStevenson here you go: https://github.com/yolpsoftware/debug-firebase-memory Start the project as an iOS Expo app, simulator or device. Expo Go works fine. Shake the device to enable the performance monitor. The performance monitor initially shows a memory consumption of around 500 MB. Then click the "Load Pages" button. Memory consumption will go to around 3 GB while 1'000 documents of 100 kB each are loaded. Then terminate the app (no reload, you need to shut down the process), restart it and click again. This time, they're loaded from AsyncStorage. Memory consumption is only ~750 MB.

Comment: @DougStevenson For the record, it's a [known bug](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/6118) that only affects the Javascript Engine of Safari. So the obvious solution is to switch your React Native app to Hermes. I tested it and it works fine. Instead of 14 GB of retained memory, we have now an overhead of a few hundreds of megabytes of memory, and after the data load, this memory is GC'ed.